# Delete/update table entries by joining 2 tables on Google BigQuery without import/export

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a usecase where we have hundreds of millions of entries in a table and have a problem splitting it up further. 99% of operations are append-only. However, we have occasional updates and deletes which Google itself says is only possible by deleting a table and creating a new one with the latest data.

Because it's a lot of data and we would wish to update the tables within 30 seconds or so, we thought about the possibility of joining an **Original table** with a **Refresher Table** in a way that we only have entries that appear in Original Table but not in Refresher Table (case of delete) or write items with data from Refresher Table if found (case of update). Output/target should be **New Table**, which we would then copy back to Original Table with WRITE_TRUNCATE (overwrite). If update seems to be too complex, we could live with a delete-only logic and re-insert the updated items ourselves.

Is this possible? What type of join seem to be a best fit? We'd stream insert our updates into the Refresher Table and periodically clean up the Original table. We would not have to pay for re-inserting the whole Original table (whether its time or money) but only for querying' once and those few streaming inserts to update-table.

*EDIT: We can live with querying stale data until the periodic merge took place. We can also halt queries for short amount of time during maintenance.*

Any thoughts welcome.

Comment: Why don't you just accept the updates as a new row in your table, and have queries that read only the last row from the table? That's much easier. Did you considered this?

Comment: That sounds like an option we should evaluate / benchmark too! Thanks for this brilliant input. We'll have to check out which one interferes the least with our ongoing queries. We'd be still interested in how joins could do the job. It's prolly an anti-join?

Answer (score 2):

So to add more on my comment:

> Why don't you just accept the updates as a new row in your table, and
>   have queries that read only the last row from the table? That's much
>   easier.

Create a view like this:

```
select * from (
SELECT 
rank() over (partition by user_id order by timestamp desc) as _rank,
*
FROM [db.userupdate_last] 
) where _rank=1
```

and update your queries to query the view table and your basic table and you are done.

Some context how we use this. We have an events table that hold user profile data. On every update we append the complete profile data row again in BQ. That means that we end up having a versioned content with as many rows for that user_id as how many updates they have done. This is all in the same table, and by looking at the time we know the order of the updates. Let's say the table us: [userupdate]. If we do a

```
select * from userupdate where user_id=10
```

it will return all updates made by this user to their profile in random order.

But we created a view, which we created only once, and the syntax is above. And now when we:

```
select * from userupdate_last where user_id=10 #notice the table name changed to view name
```

it will return only 1 row, the last row of the user. And we have queries where we just swap the table name to view name, if we want to query from a table holding a bunch of append only rows only the last one.

Comment: Note the edit to original question. We'd like to keep our queries simple and pay the price of stale data for an hour or so in case of updates. We are still interested in the join approach because it would not interfere with existing queries without adding something like GROUP BY userid ORDER BY version and LAST() on all read queries. We assume this will save us a second or two for normal queries compared to your approach. Is that incorrect?

Comment: So if you create the above as a view, in your queries you don't need to add any group by or order by or something like that, just change the table name. Try out this easy step. I will add more context to hove we use it.

Comment: Thanks again, we'll evaluate that! Looks like if we query with a simple WHERE version IS NULL we can query the stale data at lowest possible cost (time & money) - you approach is very interesting though because it provides queries against live data! What about deletes, though? Would be nice if we don't have to filter by something like deleted IS NULL all the time.

Comment: filtering like deleted is null is no perf hit to BQ, and even can be directly compiled in the view itself

Answer (score 0):

There is relatively simple option we found efficient in similar scenarios with BigQuery.
It allows to handle queries based on any time based snapshot – as well as query current snapshot

In short, idea is in having one master table and daily history tables
During the day - current daily table is used for insertions (new, update, delete) and then daily process does merge of last completed daily table with master table writing it out back to same master table. Of course, first, backup is taken via copy of latest master table (free operation).

Daily master table update process allows to keep master table clean and fresh as of last day.
Now at any given moment you can have most recent data by querying only (junk-less) master table and today's table only.
At the same time, as you have all daily tables, you can query any historical data

Of course, classic option of adding all data (new, update, delete) into the master table with respective qualifiers still looks good both price and performance wise because your main (99%) data are new entries!

In your case, me personally, I would vote for classic approach with periodic cleaning of historical entries

Finally, in my mind, it is less about joining, but rather about [union](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#from) with use of [table wildcard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions) and [window](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions) functions