# Switching a BigQuery table into "readonly mode"

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to ensure that a table in BigQuery can no longer receive any inserts (be it "load/batch" inserts or "streaming" inserts).
Is there any possibility to turn a table into a "readonly mode"?

I would like to avoid playing with the standard IAM / access control whose smallest level of permissions is the dataset level. If there were an option to force "readonly" on 1 table for all the users independently of their role (just like when you force a filesystem in "readonly mode"), that would be awesome.

(final goal is to do a safe merge of a "master" and "update" table as explained here: [Delete/update table entries by joining 2 tables on Google BigQuery without import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838622/delete-update-table-entries-by-joining-2-tables-on-google-bigquery-without-impor/34838747#34838747) ).

Comment: You could do this by keeping all tables in a dataset with limited access and then creating views (which are naturally read-only) over the tables in a different dataset. Swap a table out for a view to make it read only. Does that work? Some organizations have a "production" dataset with only read access, for instance. I can write up a more complete answer if this sounds feasible.

Comment: I thought about that, but then that would mean creating 2 datasets for each "master" table that I have (1 dataset for the current "update" table that I want to merge, and 1 dataset for the new "update" table that is going to receive the new data when my merge process is finished). So that becomes a hell of many datasets I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible in BigQuery. You can submit feature request at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0

Meantime, workaround would be to use Snapshot decorators.
So, without restricting adding rows to table, you will be able to get table state at any moment (within last two weeks if I remember correctly) - so indirectly this will give you what you want

Snapshot decorators are [available in Legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators#snapshot_decorators) and I think they recently were [added to Standard SQL](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905931)

Comment: Works indeed for consistency. I was also thinking of using some filtering on the EventTimestamp column that we add to every row.  

However, with this approach I am not able to "truncate" the "update table", because DML/delete operations are not enabled on streaming tables according to https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language (well, at least I could use that approach when I do micro batches instead of streaming).

Comment: filtering can be more expensive code wise and in case if table continue grow - it will incur whole table scan (so extra $$). consider voting up the answer if it helped somehow :o)

Comment: As suggested, I've filled a feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68743496