# Run delete query from python in BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm using the following python code to delete some rows in a bigquery table:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project='my-project')

query_delete = f"""
    delete from `my_table` where created_at >= '2021-01-01'
"""
print(query_delete)
# query_delete
job = bigquery_client.query(query)
job.result()
print("Deleted!")
```

However, the rows don't seem to be deleted when doing this from python. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried running the same query query from the Cloud Console? Does it work there?

Comment: Yes of course, it works from the console

Comment: Alright. Have you tried running a non-delete query from your Python client? Including just querying and trying to modify records such as insert/update?

Comment: I'm assuming that it's a typo where you assign `query_delete` but then pass `query` to the job?

Comment: Some other common issues that might apply here: Billing is enabled for this project? The service credential has been assigned dataset & bigquery owner level permissions?

Comment: Can you do a print(job.result()) to see if there are any exceptions?

Comment: it was a typo indeed that was causing the error, oh damn :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think below code snippet should work for you. You should pass `query_delete` instead of `query`

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project='my-project')

query_delete = f"""
  delete from `my_table` where created_at >= '2021-01-01'
"""

print(query_delete)
job = bigquery_client.query(query_delete)
job.result()
print("Deleted!")
```

Or you can try below formatted query

```
query_delete = (
  "DELETE from my_table "
  "WHERE created_at >= '2021-01-01'"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enable standard SQL in BigQuery table.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42831957/1683626

It should be set as default as is noted in [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql), but maybe you changed it to legacy sql.

> In the Cloud Console and the client libraries, standard SQL is the default.